# Download csv file which has javascript on-click download with requests

Tags: python, ajax, python-requests

I'm trying to download a csv file from here: [Link](https://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/NegociosRealizados) after clicking on "Acesse todos os negócios realizados até o momento", which is in blue next to an image of a cloud with an arrow.

I do know how to solve the problem with selenium, but it's such a heavy library that I'd like to learn another solutions (specially faster ones). My main idea was to use requests, since **I think** it's the fastest approach.

My code:

```
import requests

url="https://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/NegociosRealizados/Registro/DownloadArquivoDiretorio?data="
r=requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)
r.text
```

r.text is a string of 459432 characters gives the following output (just put some part of it here):

```
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...
```

I don't know what this string is or what to do with it. Is it encoded? Should I call another function with it? Am I calling the wrong link? Should I just try another approach? Is selenium not that bad?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Extra info:
From devtools I found it's calling these javascript functions: [image]

onclick is just that: `<a href="#" onclick="carregarDownloadArquivo('')">`

carregarDownloadArquivo (I don't know java, tried to extract only this specific function inside the js):

```
function carregarDownloadArquivo(n){var t;
t=n!=null&&n!=""?n:getParameterByName("data")==null?"":getParameterByName("data");
$("#divloadArquivo").show();
$.ajax({url:"/NegociosRealizados/Registro/DownloadArquivoDiretorio?data="+t}).then(function(t,i,r){var u;
if(t!="null"&&t!=""){var f=convertBase64(t),e=window.navigator.userAgent,o=e.indexOf("MSIE ");
(n==null||n=="")&&(n=retornaDataHoje());
u=n+"_NEGOCIOSBALCAO.CSV";
o>0||!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)?DownloadArquivoIE(u,f,r.getAllResponseHeaders()):DownloadArquivo(u,f,r.getAllResponseHeaders())}$("#divloadArquivo").hide()})}
```

Extra functions to understand carregardownload:

```
function DownloadArquivoIE(n,t,i){var r=new Blob(t,{type:i});
navigator.msSaveBlob(r,n)}function DownloadArquivo(n,t,i){var r=new Blob(t,{type:i});
saveAs(r,n)}function getParameterByName(n,t){t||(t=window.location.href);
n=n.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"\\$&");
var r=new RegExp("[?&]"+n+"(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),i=r.exec(t);
return i?i[2]?decodeURIComponent(i[2].replace(/\+/g," ")):"":null}
```

Not so sure about ajax and send calls. Also I don't know how their code is downloading the csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to decode the base64-encoded response from the server:

```py
import base64
import requests

url = "https://bvmf.bmfbovespa.com.br/NegociosRealizados/Registro/DownloadArquivoDiretorio?data="

t = base64.b64decode(requests.get(url).text)
print(t.decode("utf-8"))
```

Prints:

```
Data/Hora da ultima atualizacao: 11/11/2022 16:38:20
Instrumento Financeiro;Emissor;Codigo IF;Quantidade Negociada;Preco Negocio;Volume Financeiro R$;Taxa Negocio;Origem Negocio;Horario Negocio;Data Negocio;Cod. Identificador do Negocio;Cod. Isin;Data Liquidacao
DEB;STAGENEBRA;MSGT23;2200;980,96524400;2158123,54;7,8701;Pre-registro - Voice;16:34:56;11/11/2022;#97441063;BRMSGTDBS050;12/11/2022
CRA;VERTSEC;CRA022006N5;306;972,49346900;297583,00;,0000;Pre-registro - Voice;16:34:49;11/11/2022;#97441055;BRVERTCRA2S9;11/11/2022
CRI;VIRGOSEC;21L0823062;96;1012,81900600;97230,62;,0000;Pre-registro - Voice;16:33:21;11/11/2022;#97441034;BRIMWLCRIAF2;11/11/2022
CRI;VIRGOSEC;21L0823062;356;1012,81900600;360563,57;,0000;Pre-registro - Voice;16:32:55;11/11/2022;#97441028;BRIMWLCRIAF2;11/11/2022
COE;;IT5322K6C2H;10;1000,00000000;10000,00;;Registro;16:31:52;11/11/2022;#2022111113338428;;11/11/2022

...and so on.
```

Comment: How did you know which base to decode? Didn't find anything about base64 when I looked into the site's code.
It's the first time I'm using a decoder, so I'm very unexperienced on the subject

Comment: @VictorReial You can open Web developer tools and in debugger search for javascript function `carregarDownloadArquivo`. There you will see the script is base64-decoding the downloaded data.